# How to send data into two attributes at once?

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

I have a `textfield`, where user can enter event. I have two buttons `oncbtn(tag:0)` and `ofcbtn(tag:1)`, which users can select. For example if user enters `History101` and select both buttons,it should be saved in both the attributes `eventNameOnc` and `eventNameOfc`. What do I need to add here for this to happen

```
 @IBAction func eventSave(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let eventInformation = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "EventSchedule", into: context)

if sender.tag == 0 { // oncbtn
        eventInformation.setValue(eventTextField.text, forKey: "eventNameOnc")
    }
    else if sender.tag == 1 { // ofcbtn
        eventInformation.setValue(eventTextField.text, forKey: "eventNameOfc")
    }
        do
        {
            try context.save()
        }
        catch{}      
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add a @IBAction to detect the button click event.

```
@IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if sender.tag == 0 { // oncbtn
        eventInformation.setValue(eventTextField.text, forKey: "eventNameOnc")
    }
    else if sender.tag == 1 { // ofcbtn
        eventInformation.setValue(eventTextField.text, forKey: "eventNameOfc")
    }
}
```

Comment: That's right but can you add button action in another button action method. I edited my question, please look at it.

Comment: there is no need to do that. you can just link those two buttons to the same `IBAction` and use `tag` attribute to distinguish them.

Comment: Well I did that, but since they are under eventSave button, as soon as you click one button, it is saving even before I click save and not giving me time to click another button. Edited question again for your reference

Comment: Well, it's a tricky question. When a button clicked, you can fire an event. (save attribute) You will never know whether the second button will be clicked or not. So the scenario seems fine with me. IMO, you should use a checkboxes and ONE button to do what you want to do.